# Mandrill validation in ruby, lost in translation between php and ruby

Tags: php, ruby, base64, hmac, mandrill

I'm trying to follow the steps Mandrill has outlined here http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23704122-Authenticating-webhook-requests in order to validate incoming requests. I've setup a test requestb.in with the url seen in the code. I want this method to return the mandrill signature, which in this case is H7Zky1B/GShKH4kuQcfUhNrQq+k= but instead it returns a different value each time. Where am I going wrong?

php code sample as provided by mandrill

```
function generateSignature($webhook_key, $url, $params) {
    $signed_data = $url;
    ksort($params);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $signed_data .= $key;
        $signed_data .= $value;
    }

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signed_data, $webhook_key, true));
}
```

my ruby code

```
 def valid?(params)
    wh_key = "Ny_lzk4zxENbNVezqECBxw"
    url = "http://requestb.in/15wvu0y1"
    signed_data = url
    params.sort.each do |key, value|
      signed_data += (key.to_s + value.to_s)
    end
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')
    Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest,signed_data,wh_key)}") 
  end
```

Comment: have you tried '/15wvu0y1' for the url instead of the full url?

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need the full URL, including the `http://` at the beginning. It looks like the parameters you're passing in the second to last line may not be in the correct order.  This should work, though, assuming the parameters have already been form-decoded:

```
def valid?(webhook_key, url, params, signature)
  data = url
  params.sort.each {|k,v| data = url + k + v}
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
  expected = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, webhook_key, data)).strip
  expected == signature
end
```

Comment: Also important to note that the params noted above are the POST params (including the mandrill_events param from Mandrill) and NOT the params attached to the Webhook Route

Comment: @JeremyHaile - I'd recommend starting a new topic with information about what specifically isn't working, or getting in touch with the Mandrill support team via the Support button in your account. If it's not working, more details would be needed about the specific issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
data = "http://my_awesome.com/api/webhook_action"

request.POST.sort_by { |key, value| key.to_i }.each do |key,value|

    data += key.to_s.strip
    data += value.to_s.strip

end

digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
expected = Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest,test_key, data)}").strip
```

The strip methods might be overkill though.

Comment: This worked for me too! I needed the last `strip` call for it to work.